# I don't want to ignore a file with no extension

Tags: docker, digital-ocean

I have a `credentials` file with no extension.

I would like to add this file to the docker to be available in the `app` directory.

Right now I have a file added in the root of the application but after building the image the file is missing

My `dockerignore`

```
**/.classpath
**/.dockerignore
**/.env
**/.git
**/.gitignore
**/.project
**/.settings
**/.toolstarget
**/.vs
**/.vscode
**/*.*proj.user
**/*.dbmdl
**/*.jfm
**/azds.yaml
**/bin
**/charts
**/docker-compose*
**/Dockerfile*
**/node_modules
**/npm-debug.log
**/obj
**/secrets.dev.yaml
**/values.dev.yaml
LICENSE
README.md
```

Comment: When I test with a .dockerignore file like yours, the credentials file gets copied into the container as it should. Can you show the relevant parts of your Dockerfile? Also, how do you determine that the file is missing?

Comment: Are you running your build locally with `docker build`? Do you use a volume at runtime? Verify this is docker and not some other app impersonating docker. Include the build command, and the command/output you use to verify the file is not included in your image.

Answer (score 0):

Try `+([^.])`

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87649

> The bash extended glob +([^.]) will match files without any . in their name. It requires that you have not unset shopt extglob (on modern bash installations, it should be set by default). The pattern means:
>
> > any number (but at least one) of characters other than .